# How do I add int field into ListView?

Tags: string, winforms, listview, c++-cli

So I'm trying to fill a table, which is made by using ListView. "a" is some int, and obviously I can not just add an item like this, cuz it asks for string^. How do I convert my int to this string^? And what's the difference between usual string and string^?

```
System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^ listView1Item;
private: System::Windows::Forms::ListView^  listView1;

...

listView1Item = gcnew Windows::Forms::ListViewItem(a);
listView1->Items->Add(listView1Item);
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert `int a` to a string, call [`a.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t7dwaa5.aspx). ToString is defined on the .Net base class `Object`, so just about everything has a [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) you can call. (Since you're in C++/CLI, things that are purely unmanaged will not have a ToString method. But anything that's managed, or primitives that are also used in .Net (e.g., `int`), will.)

As for the difference between `String` and `String^`, I'm not sure exactly what you mean by the "usual string". I'm not sure whether you're referring to C++'s [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/), or to .Net's [`System::String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx), just without the `^`. `String^` refers to the .Net System::String class, as a manged reference. Managed references are roughly equivalent to unmanaged pointers, but the garbage collector is allowed to move things around as it does its work, and the managed reference continues to point at the proper object.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was:

```
System::Convert::ToString()
```

Thx everybody for help =)